# Wrong minimum in layer properties when displaying raster with classified symbology in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, statistics, display

I display a raster in ArcMap with classified symbology. ArcMap calculates a minimum of 274,9 for this raster. However, this raster has at least one pixel with value less than 274,9 as the information panel of `Identify` shows. How can I enforce ArcMap to use the entire value range?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS computes statistics from samples in the symbology process. You need to help ArcGIS to compute as sometimes `NoData`-values are the problem. Do the following in ArcCatalog:

- Right-click the raster > choose `Raster Dataset Properties`
- In panel `General`:

  1. `Raster Information` \ `NoData Value`: provide a `NoData`-value if it exists for the raster
  2. `Statistics`:

     - Choose `Options` > `Calculate Statistics...`
     - Enter `NoData`-value into the field `Ignore Values (optional)` and add this value with the `+`-sign to the list below this field
- Close all windows with `OK`

This handling should help ArcGIS to consequently exclude `NoData`-values from statistics-calculation and, by this, to find the correct minimum and maximum values.